# _viewstart.cshtml conditional layout.cshtml getting error This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have 2 roles admin and employee in my website and 2 layout.cshtml as well. In my _viewstart.cshtml file

```
@{
   if (!ReferenceEquals(Session["Role"], null))
    {
        if (Session["Role"].ToString() == "Admin")
        { Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml"; }
        else
        { Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_EmployeeLayout.cshtml"; }

    }
   else
   {
       Response.Redirect("~/");
   }

}
```

Everything is working fine but the else part where if session is equal to null than i am redirecting to login page "~/". It is redirecting there also on the logon page but problem is that in the logon view i have some css link and script links when ever a request goes to server for script or .css file. server again redirect to the _viewstart.cshtml and again all the process executing, and i am getting this error

This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at localhost address has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Please suggests me solution or let me know where I am wrong here in my code

1.Is _viewstart.cshtml  executes with every request not only with views ?
2. How can i remove this error?

Comment: Which layout are you going to use if Session["Role"] is null?

Comment: if session is null than i am redirecting to the login view and login view does not have  any layout view associated with it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Response.Redirect why dont you use [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470154)

Comment: how in razor i used there Response.RedirectToRoute("Login");
but getting notimplementedexception error

Comment: @Himanshu please put this in your question and update it, this will help us to answer quickly

Comment: @HatSoft : what should i put in question ?

Answer (score 0):

`_ViewStart.cshtml` will be called every time a view is going to be rendered.

In the condition you are using two types of layouts one for admin and other for employee.

**What layout you are going to use for an anonymous user?**

For anonymous user obviously `Session["Role"]` will be null and you again redirecting to the login action that again outputs a view which again calls the `_ViewStart.cshtml` so you are in a loop.

I guess you should not do the redirect to login page in the `_ViewStart.cshtml` basically it should be taken care by the **Authorization** filters.

You can change the condition like this,

```
@{
   if (!ReferenceEquals(Session["Role"], null))
    {
        if (Session["Role"].ToString() == "Admin")
        { Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml"; }
        else
        { Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_EmployeeLayout.cshtml"; }

    }
   else
   {
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_GeneralLayout.cshtml";
   }
}
```

Comment: yes before i was not redirecting but at that time views are redering without .css they were not redirecting to the login page after session expired thats why i added that code. and we do same in web forms master page so i putted this code. 
with your solution i have to take one more layout view because nothing is happening with authorization

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, @Mark is right. The `_ViewStart.cshtml` is always called, even for pages without a layout. So, you are in a loop. So, use this in your `_ViewStart.cshtml`

```
@{
    if (!ReferenceEquals(Session["Role"], null))
    {
        if (Session["Role"].ToString() == "Admin")
        { Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml"; }
        else
        { Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_EmployeeLayout.cshtml"; }
    }
    else
        Layout = null;
}
```

Then, create a BaseController class, add the following method to it and make all your controllers extend it.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(Session["Role"], null))
        Redirect("~/");

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```